# How to make UIScrollView same design and appearance all iPhone version such us iPhone 5s , 6 6s ,...... 8plus , iPhonx by using code

Tags: ios

I developing simple by code instead of storyboard the application has UIScrollView which has 10 button in iOS using objective c, after I developed the app and I tested in all simulator such us 5s , 6plus , 6s 8plus iPhonex , I get a problem in the appearance and layout. the appearance is so different. 
How to make  UIScrollView same design and appearance all iPhone version such us iPhone 5s , 6 6s  ,...... 8plus , iPhonx.

Comment: Please share screenshots of devices

Comment: By properly using auto layout, go through a tutorial on how to use auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you have same layout of all buttons, then use `UIStackView` instead of `UIScrollView`. UIStack view will take care of appearance automatically.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview?changes=_6

Comment: A scroll view might still be needed - if the buttons are big enough they may not look good when swueezed on smaller screens.

Comment: UIStackView will take care of it

Comment: How? As far as I know, stack views don’t support scrolling by themselves - you need to embed them in a scroll view. If the buttons are supposed to be big, the stack view will squeeze them, and they may not look good (or the stack view will be drawn outside of screen bounds and some buttons will not be usable)

Comment: mr pkc456 what I need is to fit my application every iPhone version screen if it is small or large.

Comment: my problem is design issue if small  I lose some of my design if iPhone large the corner there is more space can any help me